# Crystal Reports Not Working in Web Application: COMException (0x8007007F)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, shibboleth

I am currently working on upgrading an ASP.NET web application to use Crystal Reports SP31. When running the web application on our web server, I get the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007007F): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F734A321-8381-4FFD-A614-139E8906DC83} failed due to the following error: 8007007f The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F).

at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.CreateRptDoc()
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper..ctor()
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Initialize()
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor()
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass..ctor()
```

The Crystal Reports runtime (32-bit) is installed on the web server, and its IIS is configured to allow 32-bit applications. I've run the same web application on my own local machine with no problems.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update** - I've identified the cause of the issue. The server also has Shibboleth 3.3.0 installed on it, and apparently that "breaks" the Crystal Reports runtime. Unfortunately, the Shibboleth application is required, so I can't just uninstall it.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: If  you attempting to use x32 bit software? Then you have to change and set your project to run as x32 bits. (you can't use ANY CPU and you can't use x64 bits). The web server can have x32 bit applications enabled, but for your code and site to use "in process" x32 bit software, then your web site has to be ALSO running as x32 bits.

Comment: I tried setting the web application to explicitly run in 32-bit (x86) mode. No luck, unfortunately.